# Extracting Json from a Json Data in Hive

Tags: json, hive

I have the following data which is in the json format in a column called details of table named customer in Hive:

```
 {
      "customer" : {
        "given_name" : "Anuvrat",
        "surname" : "Singh"
      }, 
      "order" : {
        "id" : "123dfe523gd"
      },
    "address" : {
        "city" : "kolkata",
        "pin" : "700091"
      },
   "phone" : {
        "mobile" : "*********"
      }
    }
```

I have to remove the address and phone from the json data and the data should look like:

```
{
  "customer" : {
    "given_name" : "Anuvrat",
    "surname" : "Singh"
  }, 
  "order" : {
    "id" : "123dfe523gd"
  }
}
```

How to do(i.e update) for every row present in the table?

I tried the following command `hadoop fs -cat /home/customer/* | jq '.details[] |= del(.address,.phone)'` yet I dint get the expected output rather getting error saying

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 93
cat: Unable to write to output stream.
```

Comment: any other  way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to a solution not using Hive, I want to remark that this is something very easy to do with [`jq` command line JSON parser](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/).

Given your input file, you would do:

```
jq 'del(.address,.phone)' file
```

If you want to remove `address` and `phone` objects for all entries of the table, you can do:

```
jq '.[] |= del(.address,.phone)' file
```

Comment: How will this work in Hadoop? Can you give me some example or a link to refer?

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman I don't exactly know, but if you can execute an external command within your tool and provided that jq is installed on your system, you should be able to do what you need.

Comment: I am trying. But something is missing and I am getting error. parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 93
cat: Unable to write to output stream. I wrote the following : hadoop fs -cat /home/customer/*  | jq '.details[] |= del(.address,.phone)'

Comment: @VijayaSeetharaman This just means that the output of the command isn't the same as the example in your question. Please update your question with the result of the command and its expected output

Comment: My question and the expected output is perfectly fine. The data resides within HDFS and I was using Hive Queries to update the data in the HDFS. With your example I was trying to edit data directly in HDFS and I was getting such errors.

Answer (score 0):

This is the query which I ran to get the above result:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE customer Select id,CASE WHEN id is not null THEN concat('{"customer":',get_json_object(details,'$.customer'),',"order":',get_json_object(details,'$.order'),'"}') ELSE details END AS details  FROM customer;
```